# problem in inserting nodes into linked list

Tags: python

Recently, I've been going through data structure in python, and I came across a problem when implementing an insertion method in a linked list. Below is the code used to construct my linked list.

```
class Node:
    data = None
    next_node = None  #make sure it's initialized
    
    def __init__(self, data, next_node = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = next_node
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Node data: %s>" % self.data
    
class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insertafter(self, prev_node, data):
        current = self.head
        new = Node(data)

        while current != None:
            if current.data == prev_node:
                return current
            else:
                current = current.next_node
        
        current.next_node = new
        new.next_node = current.next_node

    def append_(self, data):
        new = Node(data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = data
        
        last = self.head
        while last.next_node != None:
            last = last.next_node
        last.next_node = new

     def __repr__(self):         
        nodes = []
        current = self.head
        
        while current != None:
            if current is self.head:
                nodes.append("[Head: %s]" %current.data)
            elif current.next_node is None:
                nodes.append("[Tail: %s]" % current.data)
            else:
                nodes.append("[%s]" %current.data)
                
            current = current.next_node
        return '->'.join(nodes)
```

it seems like I have encountered some problems in implementing the `insertafter` method.

```
def insertafter(self, prev_node, data):
        current = self.head
        new = Node(data)

        while current != None:
            if current.data == prev_node:
                return current
            else:
                current = current.next_node
        
        current.next_node = new
        new.next_node = current.next_node
```

When the method is called, it does not insert any new node into the linked list or return any result. Code as shown below. Is there anything that I've missed out in it?

```
l1 = LinkedList()
l1.append(1)
l1.append_(2)
l1.append_(3)
l1.append_(4)
l1.insertafter(2, 1000)
l1
```

Output:

```
[Head: 1]->[2]->[3]->[Tail: 4]
```

Comment: if current.data == prev_node:
                return current, you did not do any insert operation u simply returned it ,add some code here

Comment: hi @Marcus.Aurelianus, thank you for your reply! I suppose I am inserting a new node by the lines `current.next_node = new; new.next_node = current.next_node` here?

Comment: I tested with this, which is not defined method, it seems to work ok. But I dont know what's the difference between this and the method I defined. 

```l2 = l1; x = l2.head; while x.data != 2: x = x.next_node
new = Node(100); new.next_node = x.next_node; x.next_node = new; print(l2)```

Output here is ```[Head: 1]->[2]->[100]->[3]->[Tail: 4]```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `break` instead of `return`. Because a `break` statement means to jump out of the current loop, but `return` means to jump out of the function without executing codes after it. Maybe you can rewrite it like this:

```
def insertafter(self, prev_node, data):
        current = self.head
        new = Node(data)

        while current:
            if current.data == prev_node:
                break
            current = current.next_node
        
        current.next_node = new
        new.next_node = current.next_node
```

Comment: really thanks a lot @Titan! It works and I didn't know enough about this difference before this- :)